# $.ajax return legend "success"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am working with mvc 4
then I am using jquery and bootstrap but
when I execute this code which does work fine, return a legend which says "success"

```
                      cantidadelegida = $("#txtcantidad").val();
                      if (cantidadelegida < 0 || cantidadelegida > cantidad)
                      {
                          alert("Cantidad debe estar entre 0 y "+cantidad);
                          return;
                      }

                      $.when(
                                                $.ajax({
                                                    async: false,
                                                    type: "post",
                                                    dataType: "html",
                                                    url: '@Url.Action("muestradetalle", "venta")',
                                                    data: { productoid: productoid, cantidad: cantidadelegida, ventaid: ventaid }
                                                }),
                                                $.ajax({
                                                    async: false,
                                                    type: "post",
                                                    dataType: "html",
                                                    url: '@Url.Action("buscarproducto", "venta")',
                                                    data: { texto: $("#txtbuscar").val(), idventa: ventaid }
                                                })

                                                ).then(
                                                function (data1, data2) {
                                                    alert(data1);
                                                    alert(data2);
                                                    $("#divdetalle").html(data1);
                                                    $("#divtableproductos").html(data2);

                                                }
                                                );
```

this not on all calls is returned, why? 
and how can i avoid it?

this is the result I had[image]

Comment: That is probably returned from the controller. Can you post the controller code?

Comment: may be Issue in  controller code
may be u return object from controller like datatable,list etc

Comment: My Model is  a object which has a sale object, a list of product, a list of account, and a object selected_detail